# Microsoft graph Account upgrade is required to create shareable links

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I am creating the shareable links through Microsoft Graph API by following this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The response I am getting is

> #<HTTParty::Response:0x563ee09ce0d0 parsed_response={"error"=>{"code"=>"accessDenied", "message"=>"Account Upgrade is required for this operation.", "innerError"=>{"code"=>"accountUpgradeRequired", "date"=>"2020-07-13T05:17:42", "request-id"=>"abc-request-id"}}}

Steps I've done to solve this

1. I've upgraded account from trial to paid
2. I've granted the application and delegated full permissions of Sites and Files